# Sculpt Mode Breaks on Files

Tags: mesh, sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I've been having this problem for a while and I can not find a good solution and I can't find help. Basically, when I'm on a project for a good few hours this starts to happen in sculpt mode. It's like some weird form of masking, it happens on every brush including the mesh filter (used inflate as an example in pics). The only "solution" I could come up with is turning on auto-masking with the biases all the way down, which doesn't help with mesh filters and the like. Second is starting a new project and reimporting everything which isn't super practical or efficient. It's really killing my motivation to get work done knowing that at any moment it'll all just go to crap. Is anyone familiar? I'll take anything. I am actually so desperate. [File here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/149sBeBp7jUeEHNuScXs8g10y5OL4fKK9/view?usp=drive_link).

[image: Base]
[image: Mesh Filter Inflate]